# Adding a content page with links to each section and subsection

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

I am working on a thesis and need to create a contents page so that each entry is a link towards a section or subsection. The current layout I'm using is "Article".

How may I introduce a content page right after the abstract:

[image: lyx contents page]

so that the first entry (Introduction) will take the user to the Introduction section when clicked, in the PDF output document.

Comment: Try to put `\tableofcontents` where you want the Table of contents. And if you want it clickable, add the package `hyperref`

Comment: Afterwards, how do I add individual sections to the table? lyx adds the sections and subsections (and numbers the automatically). Inline latex does not seem to work with lyx primitives.

Comment: With the `section` command. For example, to write your "Introduction" title, just write `\section{Introduction}`.
You shoud visit this website: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure

Comment: Is there a way of dynamically adding the sections and subsections as well as their location within the document to the contents table?

Comment: Yes, and it is explained in every LaTeX introduction and the LyX introduction. Investing 20 minutes in reading, and you would have had all your information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within your document body, use Insert > List/TOC > Table of Contents:

[image]

This will insert a Table of Contents marker which will eventually output to a linked Table of Contents:

[image]

Also add [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) support (Document > Settings... > PDF Properties > Use Hyperref Support) to enable hyperlinks from the ToC to the respective sections within your document:

[image]

Comment: I've already figured it out earlier Today, but thanks.

Comment: @Sebi: It's part of the process here. Questions are asked, and they are hopefully answered...